# In PowerShell, How would I pass a folder with files as If I were drag and dropping them via an argument

Tags: powershell, automation, adobe, command-line-arguments, droplet

I am trying to integrate an adobe Droplet into my PowerShell script.
I have created a droplet that accepts a folder containing files that can be dragged and dropped onto the .exe file of the Droplet. I can't find out what argument exactly is Equivalent to passing files via drag and dropping a folder.

I want to avoid calling the droplet for each file separately as the files are in thousands usually.

I've tried looking up documentation, but it's pretty lacklustre on Adobe's side and so I am stuck.

My current code looks like this

```
Start-process C:\path\to\the\Droplet.exe -ArgumentList -File './files'  -wait
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to see output for Droplet.exe:

```
$FilePath = "C:\path\to\the\Droplet.exe"
$ArgumentList = "-File './files'"
cmd /s /c $FilePath $ArgumentList
```